# Website URL Redirection

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, architecture

I'm building a website/application that is used for a tennis ladder system.  If you're not sure what this is, it's basically a tournament structure where players join a ladder and are able to challenge one another to matches.  Depending on how the scoring system is set up, they move up or down the ladder in standings after submitting a match score.

I've been building the site using PHP for server-side scripting and MySQL for the database.  Everything is coming along pretty well, but I've looked at other tennis ladder sites and noticed their URLs are much simpler looking than mine when performing actions.

For instance, on my site when I click to view a ladder standings the url looks like:  myurl/ladders.php?ladderID=4.  However, another ladder's website URL looks like: https://tennisladders.net/ladders/188/

Is this done simply by modifying the .htaccess file to redirect to that particular format?

I've also noticed on that same website when you go to join a ladder it would use a url like this: https://tennisladders.net/ladders/join/1212/.  I'm wondering where a url like that might redirect to -- could it redirect to something like tennisladders.net/joinLadder.php?ladderID=1212?

I suppose I'm just confused how they seem to use very structured URLs to achieve actions on the website, whereas I only understand how to create separate .php files and pass them the name value pairs after the .php? extension to accomplish tasks.

Comment: Just google "URL rewriting" and "php routing library".

Answer (score 0):

Modern PHP sites are built around the idea of a routing layer which maps URLs to internal function calls. There's many ways of implementing this, some just some simple `.htaccess` rules that clean things up, others a more robust programmatic interface that dynamically defines them, but the principles are largely the same.

The goal of a routing system is to de-couple the URL "presentation" from the underlying filesystem layout. A URL like `/ladders.php?ladderID=4` is not only ugly, it locks you into that file structure. One like `/ladders/4` is a lot cleaner and you're not going to have trouble supporting it going forward even if you dramatically re-architect your internal layout.

Most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have some kind of routing system built-in. These come in a variety of flavours, from very lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). Find one that fits your style and needs, learn it well, and you'll be able to take advantage of thousands of community modules and add-ons, as well as a wealth of expertise baked into the platform itself.

As for that other site, it [looks like they're using Django](https://builtwith.com/tennisladders.net) which is a Python framework. It too has a [routing layer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/).